# how to add more data with mnist data to train keras model

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, mnist

I tried to recognize using mnist data as train data but failed so I want to add my train data with that so how can I train my model with mnist dataset and my own data. I tried training with my own data also but failed any suggestions are welcome .....
for example first I trained with mnist dataset followed this approach

https://medium.com/coinmonks/handwritten-digit-prediction-using-convolutional-neural-networks-in-tensorflow-with-keras-and-live-5ebddf46dc8

but the results are not satisfying so I tried to train that model by my data but looking at the results maybe I don't have enough data so now I want to train my model using mnist data + my data . so how can I do that

Comment: To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: I tried explaining a little more please help me out here @Mat

Comment: Just concatenate your data and MNIST?

Comment: can you explain how to do that @sebrockm

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways how to concatenate two `numpy` arrays. The most obvious one is probably [np.concatenate()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html)

```
import numpy as np

all_train_x = np.concatenate((mnist_train_x, my_train_x))
all_train_y = np.concatenate((mnist_train_y, my_train_y))
```

Note the double parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try `data augmentation` technique. This will increase you size of the dataset and will also improve the performance of your model. You can some useful information [here](https://medium.com/nanonets/how-to-use-deep-learning-when-you-have-limited-data-part-2-data-augmentation-c26971dc8ced).